# Parallel processing and for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have a large number of netcdf files. Each of which is 300*300=90000 grids.

I tried to open each file in a loop, make all 90000 grids as a single column, open the next file and append it to the first column etc. hence I created a dataframe, where each column represents a netcdf file with 90000 rows.

The code is as follows.

```
files= list.files("C:/cygwin64/home/Suchi",pattern="3B-HHR.MS.MRG.3IMERG.2001",full.names=TRUE)
# Loop over files
for(i in 1:files) {
  nc = ncdf4::nc_open(files[i])
  lw = ncvar_get(nc,"pcp")
  lw<-as.data.frame((lw))
  lw<-as.data.frame(t(lw))
  lw<-unlist((lw))
  lw<-data.frame(lw)
  # Add the values from each file to a single data.frame
  cbind(df,data.frame(lw))->df
  ncdf4::nc_close(nc)
}
```

The above code works fine. It is just taking too much time.
Please help me to do the same using foreach command in parallel processing. 
I am getting the following error:

```
Error unlist(ncdf4::nc_open(files[i])) : 
task 1 failed - "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

When using `foreach` parallel processing..

Comment: We cannot advise on your failling `foreach` command without seeing what you are trying.

Comment: The most likely reason for the slow performance is performing the `cbind` operation inside the loop. This is a huge consumer of memory and hampers performance. Since you know the size of your final dataframe, a very easy way to improve is to preallocate an empty dataframe outside the body of the loop and then just update the columns as needed. Examle: `df<-data.frame(x=numeric(length=100)); df[ , c(1:10)]<-numeric(length=100)`

Comment: Thanks for looking into my query. Could you please look at the code mentioned by the Mr. Aliyan below. The same is the one I used.  I also tried preallocation of empty dataframe . But parallel processing would be something more useful because I need to do it in future for more files..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your foreach loop, so I have made one for you. The error you are receiving may be due to the fact your loop is this:

```
for(i in 1:files)
```

which is wrong, since files is a vector not a number. It should instead be this:

```
for(i in 1:length(files))
```

Here is the foreach loop that I created, for your script. Let me know if this works:

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)


files= list.files("C:/cygwin64/home/Suchi",pattern="3B-HHR.MS.MRG.3IMERG.2001",full.names=TRUE)
# Loop over files


cl = makeCluster(10)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i = 1:length(files)) %dopar% {

  library(ncdf4)


  nc = ncdf4::nc_open(files[i])
  lw = ncvar_get(nc,"pcp")
  lw<-as.data.frame((lw))
  lw<-as.data.frame(t(lw))
  lw<-unlist((lw))
  lw<-data.frame(lw)
  # Add the values from each file to a single data.frame
  cbind(df,data.frame(lw))->df
  ncdf4::nc_close(nc)


}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at your code inside your loop, this line does not make sense: cbind(df,data.frame(lw))->df, for every core it looks like you are creating a new df. This does not work because every core is separate and not linked to one another, so the df for one core will mean something else for df for another core. This should be done in a different way. If you don't mind your df columns being not in order of files. I can suggest a different way.

Comment: Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection , is the error occurring by using the code mentioned above.